# Equivalence of equations for a cyclo stationary discrete random process

Tags: integration

I came across this equation in a step when finding a power spectral density of a cyclo stationary discrete random process.

$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^T f(t-kT)dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)dt
$$

How could I understand this equation? Is it like integrating a continuous time function on the RHS is equivalent to integrating all the samples over a time period T? I could not figure out a reasonable explanation for this proof. If there is any mathematical steps which leads from LHS to RHS it would be helpful. (Any conceptual reasonable proof from LHS to RHS will also help). Thanks very much.

Comment: Hint: write a few terms of the sum and see how they relate via a change of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change of variables, and then add up the integrals.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^T f(t-kT) \mathop{dt}
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-kT}^{-(k-1)T} f(u) \mathop{du} & (u=t-kT)
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \mathop{du}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Still at the end of the step if we substitute u=t-KT back, doesn't it end with f(t-kT)? But the RHS in the question is f(t).

Comment: @sundar $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \mathop{du} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \mathop{dt} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\spadesuit) \mathop{d\spadesuit}$